# Auto mount HP USB Flash drive Error

Tags: linux, usb, automounting, rhel

I am using RHEL 5, If i plug my USB Flash drive i'm getting Error message as follows,

[image]

This much days It work smoothly, And now it working with windows XP well.

Where is the problem ? How can i solve it ?

Comment: Could you rephrase "This much days It work smoothly"? Do you mean the same stick worked some days ago?

Comment: Also, could you post the messages in the tail of /var/log/messages corresponding to the failed mount attempt?

Comment: @fschmitt, thanks for ur comment. I formated my pendrive again with fedora and now it working smoothly in RHEL5 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem may be in file system formatting. Format pen drive with FAT32 file system in windows. After that it'll work properly.